# Is there a difference between "temperaturo" and "varmeco"?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

The Esperanto wikipedia defines "temperaturo" like this :

> Temperaturo estas fizika eco de materio, la bazo de la komunaj nocioj
>   "varma" kaj "malvarma".
>   (Temperature is a physical property of matter, the basis of the common notions "Hot" and "cold")

So is there a difference between "temperaturo" and "varmeco", or "temperaturo" is just one way to measure "varmeco"?

Comment: It seems to me to be the same as _temperature_ and _warmth_ in English. One is precisely measurable (temperature in degrees) whereas the other is rather fuzzy (warmth).

Answer (score 8):

I believe that *varmeco* is not a physical quantity. It's just a quality of being warm (Oliver Manson has the best translation: warmth). It can be compared to some extent but does not have any proper scale. The examples from Vortaro all fall into this usage:

> - la varmeco k beleco de ĉi tiu nekonata paradizo
> - la varmeco de liaj sentoj kontraŭ mi, de lia akceptado, de lia parolo min surprizis
> - meti en la diskuton multe da varmeco.

On the other hand, *temperaturo* is not *eco* but *grando*:

> - oni mezuras temperaturon laŭ la skalo celsia (en °C), kelvina (en K) aŭ (nun malofte) laŭ la farenhejta (en °F)
> - la temperaturo (de la ĉambro) devas esti almenaŭ ses gradojn pli alta
> - kia estas la ĉimatena temperaturo?
> - altaj, malaltaj temperaturoj
> - absoluta temperaturo

Comment: *varmeco* or *varmo* is a phisical quantity, but not the same as *temperaturo*.

https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varmo
https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperaturo

Comment: @JohannesMueller I agree about *varmo*, but is *varmeco* indeed another name for that?

Comment: Well, the use of *-ec-* is often arguable. Maybe come up with an example sentence, that changes its meaning when replacing *varmo* with *varmeco*.

Comment: If we are going to split the hairs between "varmeco" and "temperaturo" then it's necessary to split them just as fine when discussing "varmo" and "varmeco."

Comment: @JohannesMueller *"Tiu ruĝa muro radias agrablan varmecon."* I think with *varmeco* this is a question of aesthetic assessment whereas with *varmo* it's most likely untrue, unless the wall is red because it has 1000°C.

Answer (score 3):

- temperaturo = tempurature
- varmeco = warmness

What is the temperature outside? (temperaturo)

How warm is it today? (varmeco)

Answer (score 3):

For many speakers there is no difference between *varmeco* and *temperaturo*. If we follow PIV (and in this regard I do, at least I endeavor to), there is indeed a difference.

The confusion comes in over the meaning of *eco* and how it relates to terms in the various national languages. This is a broader question, but it's impossible to answer the original question without touching on it.

What is the difference, for example between *varmo* and *varmeco*? Between *longo* and *longeco*? Between *eblo* and *ebleco*? Between *alto* and *alteco*? It's tempting to translate these in our heads to warmth, length, possibility, and height - then jump to the conclusion that there is no difference. Indeed many very fluent speakers live their Esperanto lives for decades without noticing that there is a difference.

Look up these words in PIV and you'll begin to see the pattern. When we admire the *longecon* of a hare's ears, we're admiring how long they are. If we happen to like short ears, we would never say that we admire the *longecon* of a guinea pig's ears because a guinea pig's ears don't have *longecon*. We can say something nice about the *longo* of the guinea pig's ears, or even admire the *mallongecon* - but not the *longecon*.

- ***Temperaturo*** is an indication of how hot or how cold something is.
- ***Varmo*** is the energy, or heat, that comes off of something warm.
- ***Varmeco*** is the quality that a hot thing has.

I am not convinced that the pattern is followed 100% on all the *-eco* words. The general idea, though, is that if you are talking about the *X-eco* of something, you can usually turn around and say that this something is *X-a*.